# React-Native Expo: Background location service never end

Tags: react-native, geolocation, expo, background-process, taskmanager

Hi I'm very new to react native and facing big challenge for how to stop background processing when app is killed.

Quick Background:
Tracking location using 'expo-location' library:
                                             `await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING, { accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,  showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true, foregroundService: { notificationTitle: 'App Title', notificationBody: 'Location tracking in background',},});`
and using 'TaskManager' to process on background (ref: [Expo Task Manager](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/task-manager/#taskmanagerdefinetasktaskname-task))

It is not perfect but I can collect location data while running on foreground and background .

Major problem is... if I don't stop using stopLocationUpdatesAsync method, it continuous running even you kills app until delete the app for stop process from settings.

May I ask your precious suggestion around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To close all tasks when the app is exited you can add the following to your `App.tsx`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("STOPPING ALL REGISTERED TASKS");
      TaskManager.unregisterAllTasksAsync();
    };
  }, []);
```

You will notice your location task stops when a user closes the app.

Comment: Hi xtra thanks for your reply. Yes after day found solution to solve. As it is  async   `TaskManager.unregisterAllTasksAsync();` should be `await   TaskManager.unregisterAllTasksAsync();`